# Rename large file

Tags: c#, rename

I want to rename large files while using c#.
If I have a couple of large files and if I use .IO.move function
my files will  be copied with the right name and the old ones will be destroyed.
that will take a veryyyy long time with large files

I couldnt find a good solution.
anyone an idea fitting large files?

Comment: If you move from one volume to another, it is a copy + delete, which is unavoidable.

Answer (score 6):

Whatever solution you choose - if you move your file between different logical/physical disks - you cannot do anything with it. It takes some time to move the data.

Comment: Maybe i was a bit unclear, i want to rename a file,but i dont want to do things with the file that will cost a lot of time, like using the .io.move(oldname,newname) method

Comment: because that method will move and delete stuff, which in this case having a couple of gigabytes to handle, isnt fast

Comment: @ComputerIntelligentAgent: as long as you move files between different disks - it will always take a time to read-and-write all the file's bytes

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested your assumption?  I did, and I found that if you use `System.IO.File.Move`, and the target location is on the same <s>physical</s> logical disk as the source, the file is just renamed.  It doesn't take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a new hardlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387690/how-to-create-hardlink-in-c), then delete the original. This will only affect filesystem metadata, and not copy the file around.